# Parameter 0 of method calculationRunner in ... required a bean of type '...' that could not be found

Tags: spring-boot, java-11

**Environment:**

jdk 11

spring boot 2.1.3

**Code:**

```
 @SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner calculationRunner(Calculator calculator, 
            @Value("${lhs}") int lhs,
            @Value("${rhs}") int rhs, 
            @Value("${op}") char op) {
        return args -> calculator.calculate(lhs, rhs, op);
    }
}
public class Calculator {
    private final Collection<Operation> operations;

    public Calculator(Collection<Operation> operations) {
        this.operations = operations;
    }
    public void calculate(int lhs, int rhs, char op) {
        for (var operation : operations) {
            if (operation.handles(op)) {
                var result = operation.apply(lhs, rhs);
                System.out.printf("%d %s %d = %s%n", lhs, op, rhs, result);
                return;
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown operation " + op);
    }
}
public interface Operation {
    int apply(int lhs, int rhs);
    boolean handles(char op);
}
@Component
public class Addition implements Operation {
    @Override
    public int apply(int lhs, int rhs) {
        return lhs + rhs;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean handles(char op) {
        return '+' == op;
    }
}
```

**Console:**

```
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.3.RELEASE)

ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-03-11 15:16:13.709 ERROR 4652 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************
Description:    
Parameter 0 of method calculationRunner in com.example.demo.DemoApplication required a bean of type 'com.example.demo.Calculator' that could not be found.       
Action:
Consider defining a bean of type 'com.example.demo.Calculator' in your configuration.
```

**Structure**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fgr4b.png)

I study Spring boot on Externalize Properties,see the issue. I do know how to deal with it.

I hope you can help me to solve the issue, thank you very much.

Comment: i use maven building the jar, but maven2 unsupport jdk11

Answer (score 0):

Your `calculationRunner` method expects a bean of type `Calculator` as the first argument. But your `public class Calculator` is not a valid spring bean. Consider removing `Calculator` from the `calculationRunner` method's signature and construct the object within the method's body. Or define `Calculator` as a Spring bean separately (i. e. add `@Service` or similar annotation).